Let's maintain quality: Please review!
This is not the review queue of a healthy site.



We have issues:

Two-sentence questions with no effort
Low quality, off-topic questions that aren't being closed because there aren't enough active close-voters (only nineteen questions have been closed this year)
New users who post questions at an alarming rate. (2-3 questions daily)
Poor answers with no citations
The tagging system is being ignored
No high-rep or long-time members to help explain and advise these users
No reviewers!!

Please, please, please review. It's the best way to maintain quality.
The quality of the average post on this site has gone down significantly, and I think it's scaring users away. Let's try to bring this site back to previous standards. Thoughts?

Thanks for raising this. The users should also provide context / background on why they're asking certain questions, where did they hear about the topic from, include any sources or reasoning behind their queries, etc. since answers are being written by an actual person and not a robot

@Harihara - you're a newer user, but you're providing high-quality content. Thanks! If you'd like to submit edits to the questions you're answering, I'd be happy to approve them. Welcome to HSE. Oh, also, feel free to cast close votes on off-topic questions.

@CDR I totally agree with you. My personal opinion is any answer without a credible source should be deleted. There should be an option to flag, that the answer is without an authentic source, so it should be deleted. There is no such rule, and that is why people get away with non-sense answers.
